# Using framebuffer to draw pixel data from CUDA

Tags: c++, opengl, framebuffer

I am running CUDA code to calculate colour data for each pixel in OpenGL, which I store in a buffer object. I need to display this data on the screen. I decided to create a texture from the data and display it using a [framebuffer](https://learnopengl.com/Advanced-OpenGL/Framebuffers). However, my current code doesn't render anything on the screen. I have a few questions:

1. Why do I need a framebuffer instead of just drawing the texture to the quad?
2. Is there a shorter way to use framebuffers to render the data from the buffer? I found a tutorial with a different approach, using [drawbuffers](https://www.opengl-tutorial.org/intermediate-tutorials/tutorial-14-render-to-texture/). Would this approach change anything about my current implementation?
3. What is the correct way to update the texture/framebuffer for each frame? My idea was to use two textures, swap the texture pointers on every update, update the textures with `glTexSubImage2D()`, and bind the texture to the framebuffer.
4. How do I determine the size of buffers and textures? My program fails on the update routine (without throwing an error unfortunately), so do I have to adjust the size to be equal for the CUDA buffer and texture?

Here's the code I've written so far:

1. Create a shader program for the framebuffer

```c
#version 330 core
    
layout (location = 0) in vec2 inPos;
layout (location = 1) in vec2 inTexCoord;
    
out vec2 texCoord;
    
void main()
{
    gl_Position = vec4(inPos, 0.0, 1.0);
    texCoord = inTexCoord;
}
```

```c
#version 330 core
    
out vec4 FragColor;
in vec2 texCoord;
    
uniform sampler2D tex_A;
    
void main()
{
     FragColor = texture(tex_A, texCoord);
}
```

2. Create a framebuffer

```cpp
GLuint fb_name = 0;
glGenFramebuffers(1, &fb_name);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fb_name);

// Generate first texture
glGenTextures(1, tex_ptr_A);
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, *tex_ptr_A);

// Initialize texture with glTexImage2D
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, texture_width, texture_height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);

// Texture wrapping
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

// Texture filtering
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_BORDER);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_BORDER);

glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, *tex_ptr_A, 0);
```

3. Set uniform (`tex_A`) to 0
4. Setup two triangles to draw the texture on

Then, in the main loop:

5. Run the CUDA part to get the data
6. Update the texture with the new data

```cpp
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, FBO);

// Swap texture pointers
tex_ptr_tmp = tex_ptr_A;
tex_ptr_A = tex_ptr_B;
tex_ptr_B = tex_ptr_tmp;

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, *tex_ptr_A);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, *cuda_buffer_object);
glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0, texture_width, texture_height, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, cuda_buffer_object);

glFramebufferTexture(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, *tex_ptr_A, 0);

auto fb_status = glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER);
if (fb_status != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE)
{
    std::cout << "ERROR: FRAMEBUFFER: " << fb_status << std::endl;
}

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
```

7. Draw to the framebuffer

```cpp
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, FBO);
glClearColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

glBindVertexArray(VAO);
glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, *tex_ptr_A);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
```

Comment: *Why do I need a framebuffer instead of just drawing the texture to the quad?* No clue why you would need a framebuffer for what you describe. Who told you that framebuffers were a good solution for your problem?

Comment: @BDL I found some forum posts on drawing pixel data (can't seem to find it again though), mentioning glDrawPixels/FBO/PBO as methods without going into detail. Framebuffers are new to me, so I searched for a specific tutorial. I guess framebuffers would only be useful for some kind of post-processing then?

Comment: Framebuffers are needed when you want to render to something else than the screen (for example, to a texture). Postprocessing relies on that since you usually want to render the scene into a texture, then process the texture further. But for your use-case where you already have a texture, it doesn't really make sense.